# Deploy WCF REST 4.0 to XP IIS 5?

Tags: wcf, rest, iis-5, routes

I am trying to deploy a simple "Hello World" .NET 4.0 REST-style WCF service on WinXP (IIS5). It works fine in Cassini.

I tried to adapt the info here to me:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

but something is not clicking. Can anyone lend ideas or comments? Yes, I must stay with WinXP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered self-hosting your service instead of trying to use IIS.  That will probably be easier to do than use IIS.

Comment: I am now going down the route of creating a self-hosted service to get away from IIS. One thing I am not sure about is concurrent-use threading, however. IIS gives that for free - how can I be sure than n clients connecting to my console app will all get service without blocking?

Comment: @ScSub My experience with self-hosted WCF services is that you do not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 7):

After a fair amount of struggling I was able to successfully deploy a WCF 4.0 REST web service on XP/IIS5. For the benefit of you and others in the same situation, here's what I did (let me know if you need more detail):

1. Using VS 2010, build a deployment
   package for the project and then
   install it on the target machine
   (your web server). The following
   link will show you how to do this: http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/03/web-packaging-installing-web-packages.html
2. Make sure that your virtual directory in IIS is configured to use .NET 4 (right click on virtual directory > properties > ASP.NET tab > ASP.NET Version)
3. Configure your virtual directory to support extensionless requests (i.e. your REST API) by creating a wildcard mapping (right click on virtual directory > properties > configuration > mappings tab) with the following properties: 
   **Executable**: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll 
   **Extension**: .* 
   **Check that file exists:** unchecked 
   (Note: watch out for the bug that keeps the "OK" button on this dialog grayed out. To get around this just click in the executable textbox after entering your extension and the "OK" button should get enabled).
4. If you get an authentication error when accessing the service then turn off integrated authentication on the virtual directory. This should fix the problem if you have used the defaults in the generated web.config of your service. If you have explicitly modified the authentication mode then you will have to adapt accordingly.

Comment: Thanks BitMask777. I did not uncheck **Check that file exists**. So it made my web service cannot be run correctly.

Comment: Great steps, this got me where I needed to go after installing .NET 4.0!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case above steps dont work. There could be a problem with permissions on your App pool for that website / virtual directory , you can try to set that right and try it out.

You can refer this article for more help on this.

http://technicalwizardry.blogspot.in/2013/04/wcf-rest-service-hosted-on-iis-5.html#!/2013/04/wcf-rest-service-hosted-on-iis-5.html